# I'm writing json array to file. I'm getting [{ , , }][{ , , }][{ , , }]. I need this output [{ , , },{ , , },{ , , }]. Any Suggestions?

Tags: php, json

I'm writing json array to the file. I'm getting [{ , , }][{ , , }][{ , , }]. I need this output [{ , , },{ , , },{ , , }]. 
I'm not adding json items to the array, instead creating multiple arrays.

```
$a = array();
$new_data = array(
  'name' => $_POST["product_name"],
  'age' => $_POST["quantity_stock"], 
  'city' => $_POST["item_price"]
  );

// pushing the post data each time the page reloads with post values
array_push($a,$new_data);
$json = json_encode($a);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.json", "a+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $json);
fclose($myfile);
$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);

//output
[{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}] 
[{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}]

//How to achieve this 
[{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"},
{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are write to the file after each post request and your array `$a` will only have the post array data.

that's why you getting your file at the end look like that

```
//output
[{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}] 
[{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}]
```

so to fix this issue and get your data in the right format , each time you want to write to your file , first you need to load the data from the file and then merge it to your array `$a` and then write it again.

so this code should works in your case

```
//load file data
$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");
$a = json_decode($data, true);

$new_data = array(
  'name' => $_POST["product_name"],
  'age' => $_POST["quantity_stock"], 
  'city' => $_POST["item_price"]
  );

// pushing the post data each time the page reloads with post values
array_push($a,$new_data);
$json = json_encode($a);
$myfile = fopen("newfile.json", "w+") or die("Unable to open file!");
fwrite($myfile, $json);
fclose($myfile);
$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
```

*I initialized `$a` with the data in file and change mode in fopen to `w+`*

Answer (score 0):

Try loading the data from the file into a, appending new_array to said data, then writing this new json list object into the file.

Comment: Thank you! I will try that.

Comment: it's a little helpful but a working example provides a better answer

Answer (score 0):

There problem is with the appending data to newfile.json, Here a list already appended as a text, and after that whenever we append more text, it is appended as a text, not a json object, Therefore kindly try the following code along with your existing code:-

```
$a = array();
$new_data = array(
    'name' => $_POST["product_name"],
    'age' => $_POST["quantity_stock"], 
    'city' => $_POST["item_price"]
); 

// reading data from .json file
$data = file_get_contents('newfile.json');

// creating an array of object from the text of .json file
$tempArray = json_decode($data);

// adding our new object to array
array_push($tempArray, $new_data);

// creating json representation of the array
$jsonData = json_encode($tempArray);

// writing json representation to the .json file
file_put_contents('newfile.json', $jsonData);
```

Hope this will help.

Comment: Getting the same thing

Answer (score 0):

Managed to merge this together. There is most likely a better solution

**[array_merge](https://www.php.net/array_merge)** in official PHP documentation

**[json_decode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php)** in official PHP documentation

```
$a = [{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}]; 
$b = [{"name":"ggg","qty":"ff","price":"ff"}];

json_encode(array_merge(json_decode($a, true),json_decode($b, true)))
```

or

```
$r = [];
foreach(json_decode($a, true) as $key => $array){
    $r[$key] = array_merge(json_decode($b, true)[$key],$array);
}
echo json_encode($r);
```

Comment: posting unexplained code is bad on stackoverflow. You might get downvoted.

Comment: thanks for letting me know. I thought it would be sufficient.

Comment: Thank you! I will refer that. @bhautik

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array();
$new_data = array(
  'name' => $_POST["product_name"],
  'age' => $_POST["quantity_stock"], 
  'city' => $_POST["item_price"]
  );

// pushing the post data each time the page reloads with post values
$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
$lastIndex = count($data);
$data[$lastIndex] = $new_data;

$myfile = fopen("newfile.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");\
fwrite($myfile, json_encode($data));
fclose($myfile);

$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");
$data = json_decode($data, true);
print_r($data);
```

Comment: Thank you! I will implement.

Answer (score 0):

use below code, hope it will meet your output:

```
$data = file_get_contents("newfile.json");

$a = explode("][", $data);

$x = '';
foreach($a as $y){

    $x .= $y.",";
}

echo trim($x, ",");
```